# steps to create App in Microsoft account

Tags: azure

I am trying to create an App in Microsoft account, but really struggling to get a proper links / steps etc. After research I found this link: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-register-microsoft-authentication/, but it's not giving "DashBoard" option after successful login to Microsoft account, so that I can register an App.

I need to register "App" there to get AppID and Client Secret, so that I will be used these details for authentication in for Apache Oltu Spring OAuth2 example.

Also I got the

AUTHORIZATION_URL = https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf

TOKEN LOCATION = https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf

The screen I am getting after login into microsoft account, I don't see dashboard to register App.

Could anyone please provide steps to create App in Microsoft account?

[image]

Comment: Could anyone please reply?

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://account.live.com/developers/applications/index.  This is used for Non-Windows store apps.  If you're looking to register a Windows store app you will need to register as an app developer at https://dev.windows.com/en-us/programs/join.

The article you referenced includes the link for non-Windows store apps